# Check multiple choice answer in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb. I'm doing this student project which is a web app that generates multiple choices. After user submits answer, app checks user's answers against the correct ones to provide feed back.

I have the question bank with correct answer stored in one collection. After a user submits his answer, an array contains _id with user's choice gets sent to the nodejs backend.

To check user's answers, my approach now would be something like:

```
app.post('/submitquiz', function (req, res) {
    var  arr = [], answer;
    for (answer in req.body){
        var correctChoice = questionModel.find({_id:answer._id}).correctChoice;
        if (correctChoice != answer.choice){
            arr.push({
                '_id':answer._id,
                'correctChoice': correctChoice
            })
        }
    }
    res.send(arr);
});
```

Wanna know if there's an elegant way to do this in mongodb, is there anything built in I can utilize to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: questionModel.find is async task. and for iterating loop, you have used for loop. So it might be happened that most of the time you will get empty array in response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @BlakesSeven While we are talking of an asynchronous call here, the main question is about how to implement a multiple choice check in MongoDB.

Comment: depending on the number of answers it may be better to get all the correct answers loaded, like: `db.questionModels.find({_id: { $in: [question_id1, question_id2, .... ] }})` and then find matches in memory (you could event try to cache them, if they aren't changing). The other thing is dealing with asynchronicity.